# why Keyboard lift tabhost to top?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have set a tabhost in the bottom of screen,on the top of screen is a edittext,when i click the editext,the screen keyboard jump up,and lift tabhost to the middle of the screen.i just want tabhost keeps in the bottom,even though keyboayd diaplay.

Comment: have you solved it? Coz I remember I had the same problem and solved it.. I will post tomorow

Comment: yes, I have solved it.i add InputMethod="adjust...." in manifest, thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For all facing this problem,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

[check this link: SoftKeyboard problem with Tabhost on bottom of screen](http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/softkeyboard-problem-with-tabhost-on.html)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Also, you need to disclose your affiliation when you link to your own blog.

Comment: @BilltheLizard please can you explain more about disclosing my affiliation?

Comment: Sure.  There's a [relevant section in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) that you should read, but key point is that "you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers."  Otherwise it starts to look like spam.  Also, since answers that contain *only* a link are strongly discouraged, you can see that this answer has two problems.  The answer you post should fully answer the question, with the link added for reference.

Comment: but that is not working when we use edittext in scrollview because that time scrollview not shrink. so instead of that use  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 5):

Add this attribute of activity tag in your AndroidManifest file for TabActivityClass

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```